# downloadButton function in shiny dashboard not working

Tags: r, shiny

I want to write data table output to csv when user clicks in the button. I have written following code in r for the download functionality

```
ui.r

tabItem(tabName = "output",
          h2("Resource Predictions"),
          fluidRow(
              box(
                width = 3, status = "info",solidHeader = TRUE,
                title = "QC Assignment",
                tableOutput("qc_assign")
            ),
              box(
                width = 9, status = "info",solidHeader = TRUE,
                title = "ITV Assignment",
                DT::dataTableOutput("itv_seq")
            )),

          fluidRow(
            downloadButton("downloadtable", "Download ITV assignment file",style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; width: 230px;color: blue;"))

    ),
```

And my server.r file looks like following

```
qc_assignment <- reactive({
 . 
 .
 .
list(ITV_assign = itv_assign)

})


output$downloadtable <- downloadHandler(
itv_seq <- qc_assignment()[['ITV_assign']],
filename = function() {paste("ITV_assignement_",input$ves_arrv_date,".csv",sep="")},
content = function(file){ write.csv(itv_seq, file) }
)
```

When I click on `Download ITV assignment file` button,file browser opens up and it is saving the file with the name of `downloadtable` with no `.csv` extension.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

`downloadHandler` has specified arguments:

`downloadHandler(filename, content, contentType = NA, outputArgs = list())`

I guess R is trying to match your `itv_seq <-`-Assignment to one of the remeaining arguments. This works:

```
output$downloadtable <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {    
         paste("ITV_assignement_",input$ves_arrv_date,".csv",sep="")
    },
    content = function(file){
         itv_seq <- qc_assignment()[['ITV_assign']],
         write.csv(itv_seq, file)
    }
)
```

You could add the argument `contentType = 'text/csv'`, but this is guessed from the extension you provided.

Comment: I did what you suggested,but still its saving it as `downloadtable` with no `.csv` extension

Comment: Does the example `https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/downloadHandler.html` work for you?

Comment: Above link does not exist. `404 not found`

Comment: I think it is working correctly. I am assuming you are launching the app using RStudio. In this case it does open a file browser and the name of the file will be the same as your function without the extension. However if you use the `Open in Browser` option on top of the page that opens when you run the app, it should now open the app in a web browser. If you try the download now, it should work as expected with the specified filename and extension.